# What are the differences between the first and second object in the created azure function?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

When i run command

```
func new --name getTodo
```

i get the following code in my function.json file

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
      ],
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

so i have two objects in array - what is the difference between the first and the second one ? What are the meanings of  "direction": "in", vs  "direction": "out", in the second object ?

Answer (score 0):

One means trigger, and another is output binding. Both of them is http.

The trigger give input data by http request, and output binding output data in http response.